# Convert List base object to Json string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

Currently I try to convert List object to Json string, this drive me crazy on my ASP.net MVC project.

Model:

```
public class PagerBase<T>:List<T> where T:EntityBase
{
    public int totalpage {get;set;}
    public int pageindex {get;set;}
    public int pagesize  {get;set;}

    public PagerBase(IEnumerable<T> source, int totalpage , int pageindex ,int pagesize)
    {
        this.totalpage = totalpage ;
        this.pageindex = pageindex;
        this.pagesize = pagesize;
        this.AddRange(source);
    }
}
```

My Action like this

```
public JsonResult GetClient()
{
    int pagesize=20;
    int pageindex1;

    var providers = getclient(20,1);
    var totalpage= gettotalpage(20);

    var pagerclient=new PagerBase<Client>(providers,totalpage,pageindex,pagesize);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var jsonstring=serializer.Serialize(pagerclient);
    JsonResult jr = Json(new
    {
        Html = jsonstring,
        Message = "Ok"
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return jr;
}
```

I want result at least include `totalpage`, `pagesize`, `pageindex` but actually I got empty string if there is no client.

Comment: I see so many of these questions and still just can't understand why anyone is using this shitty `JsonResult` library (other than maybe because it's in `system.web.mvc` but that's not a good reason). If you're open to using json.NET instead I will provide an answer but that `JsonResult` class is just a joke and I won't bother trying to correct any code that uses it :p

Comment: Thank you answer my question, my question is not about JsonResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON can't encode data that both has properties and is an array. I'm sure you could write a [custom serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) if you use Json.NET, but if possible, it'd be easier to just refactor your class a bit:

```
public class PagerBase<T> where T:EntityBase
{
    public List<T> items {get;set;}
    public int totalpage {get;set;}
    public int pageindex {get;set;}
    public int pagesize  {get;set;}

    public PagerBase(IEnumerable<T> source, int totalpage, int pageindex, int pagesize)
    {
        this.items = source.ToList();
        this.totalpage = totalpage;
        this.pageindex = pageindex;
        this.pagesize = pagesize;
    }
}
```

As an aside, I'd recommend you switch to [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json). It's much better than `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: BTW, I heard lot people said Json.Net is much better, I want to know how better about Json.Net

Comment: Speed, flexibility, ease of use, etc. Near the bottom of the Json.NET web site, it has a list of features of it vs other libraries. I'd say the biggest difference for you is the ease of customizing things.

Comment: I just review json.Net web site, it does lot feature compare MS's function, I will go this right now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ericyu67 I would say Tim's assessment is pretty accurate. For me the big thing is it's no more difficult for the common use cases but is way more full featured than `JsonResult` so when you want to do more advanced things it's an option. If you build a big project using `JsonResult` everywhere then find you need to do something more advanced you're going to be between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: You are right, I do lot thing base on JsonResult because I may don't know there is another option can do move advance. Now I realize there is something can be improve.